# DataGridView doesn't populate with data from databindings

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am using windows forms and VS 2010. I have a datagridview and I want to populate this datagridview with data. I wrote a stored procedure on database and created binding source in my project, from which I call stored procedure. I can even see data in the databinding's preview, but I don't know how to show that data in my datagridview. I have set datasource property in datagridview, but it is still not showing any data. Should I use some extra method to populate datagridview with data from databindings ?

EDIT:

I have used this in my code:

```
dgvKorisnici.DataSource = bsCM_USER_LIST.DataSource;
```

Comment: My previous answer was incorrect, sorry about that. Do you have a GetData() method on your form? It seems you may need to call that. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: in dgv edit columns and chek DataProperyName